# How to do exponential growth in Python looped?

Tags: python, percentage, addition, exponential

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to do percentage addition in Python? I want to add exponential percentage growth to a given number i.e. 3% addition to 150 = 154.5, and then 3% to the new value but in a continuous string an x number of times.

like so:

```
1.) 150
2.) 154.5
3.) 159.135
4.) 163.90905
5.) 168.8263215
6.) 173.891111145
7.) 179.10784447935
8.) 184.4810798137305
9.) 190.0155122081424
10.) 195.7159775743867
```

Would love to be able to do this for 200 times and print in one go.

Comment: Please provide us with code you made so far, so we can help you , without code we cant help you.

Comment: Can you focus and clarify your question on the exact problem? Are you finding difficulties in calculating the new value? Are you having problems doing it in a loop? How would you do this if you had to do it with a pen and paper? From there the transition to Python is really straightforward with basic loops

Comment: I mean, do you know how to add 3% to a number, outside of Python?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

Create a generator used to do the exponentional percentage:

```py
def expo_generator(x):
    while True:
        yield x
        x = x + x*3/100
```

Create a `take` utility (it takes n elements of a generator or array). (This util can be found also in more-itertools package)

```py
from itertools import islice
def take(n, iterable):
    return list(islice(iterable, n)
```

Then you can use:

```py
result = take(20, expo_generator(150))
```

It will return an array of the first 20 value of the expo_generator function.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to do it:

1. working with x in a loop:

```python
x = 150
for n in range(200):
    x *= 1.03  # multiplying by 103%, therefore "adding 3%"
    print(x)
```

2. mathematical way:

```python
x = 150
for n in range(200):
    print(x * (1.03**n))  # a**b means a^b, exponetial function
```